# What does "scoring tags" mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

On the blog entry [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) there is mention of "scoring tags". What does this reference to "scoring tags" mean? For example:

> Your top 40 **scoring tags**...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever voting occurs on an *answer* of yours, the tag associated with that post accrues a tally. This tally racks up over time for each possible tag you're associated with, giving you a (total) tag score:

[image]

Ranking these from highest to lower reveals your top scoring tags. The [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) mentions that the display algorithm looks only at the top 40 of such such tags associated with you.

A users list of tags sorted by score is available at the URL:

```
http://<site>/users/<userid>?tab=tags
```

[This is yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags).

<sub>A related statistic governs the awarding of the [Generalist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist).</sub>

Comment: Only votes on answers accumulate the visible score on the tag (and is used for tag badges and other badges). Question does accumulate a separate score, and only viewable if you hover over the tag, but it is not used for any badge, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Correct, thanks...

Comment: @Werner How does the score calculate?

Comment: @xshsinap: You add up all the upvotes and subtract all the downvotes of your answers based on the specific tag. This gives you a tag score for each tag.